# Why is this column not being calculated by MySQL? How can I rewrite my query so that it does?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

So, I have to write a query where, given a bunch of points with `(x, y, z)` coordinates, I need to find the closest `place` for each of the points in a list of given `place`s.

The `x, y, z` coordinates are user provided, so, are not present in the database, I am using `SELECT... UNION` to work as sort of a temp table.

The list of `place`s is actually `id`s from `places_table` (`4030764,4030734,4030752,3948...`) in my database, the `places_table` looks like -

```
CREATE TABLE `places_table` (
    `place_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `latlon_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `x` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `y` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `z` double DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Performance is ***really*** critical here so I am trying to calculate all square distances (between every point-place pair) as well as select the least distance place for each point in one go.

Here's my attempt at writing this query, (might not be a very good attempt...)

```
SELECT point.index, (@px:=point.x) AS point_x, (@py:=point.y) AS point_y, 
                    (@pz:=point.z) AS point_z, place.lat_lon_id, place.place_id, place.sq_dist FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT(latlon_id) AS lat_lon_id, place_id, (@sq_dist:=(pow(x-@px, 2) + pow(y-@py, 2) + pow(z-@pz, 2))) AS sq_dist
        FROM places_table WHERE id IN (
            4030764,4030734,4030752,3948666,4030743,4030751,4030742,4030740,4030757,4030733,4030763,4030748,4030741,
            4030735,4030744,4030753,4030737,4030736,4030731,8030076,4030739,6930873,4030727,4030758,4030726,8261466,
            4030801,4030756,4030730,4030759,7840188,7911304,4030762,4030728,4030729,6531602,4030755,4030754,4030760,
            4030749,4030750,4030761,8224616,4030738,4030732,4030746,4030747,4030745,4030871,4030872,4030790,4030787,
            3948662,4030797,4030791,4030775,4030794,4030772,4030796,4030798,3948648,4030792,4030789,4030773,4030799,
            3948661,3948651,4030788,4030778,3948657,4030800,4030795,4030793,4020117,4020363,3948663,4030777,3948658,
            3948650,4030776,4020292,4020210,3948649,4030717,3969465,3969459,4030779,4030704,4030694,4030713,8529197,
            4030873,3733656,3948664,4030786,4030781,4030783
        ) ORDER BY sq_dist LIMIT 1

) AS place, (

    SELECT           0 AS index, 1636407.74908 AS x, -2220902.79092 AS y, -5744766.34094 AS z
        UNION SELECT 1,          1674317.79921,      -2157598.66673,      -5757951.69661
        UNION SELECT 2,          1652089.75753,      -2193845.00579,      -5750671.55762
        UNION SELECT 3,          1621803.74283,      -2184916.54092,      -5762679.25265
        UNION SELECT 4,          1615277.72619,      -2200110.86847,      -5758729.88373
        UNION SELECT 5,          1652642.77785,      -2208303.65375,      -5744975.77555
        UNION SELECT 6,          1618985.40684,      -2190362.00049,      -5761404.37734
        UNION SELECT 7,          1621151.08717,      -2208242.04656,      -5753965.24636
        UNION SELECT 8,          1663760.68219,      -2166853.74959,      -5757536.37073
        UNION SELECT 9,          1639392.0856,       -2136418.33191,      -5775871.37502

) AS point ORDER BY point.index;
```

It would work but the value of `@sq_dist` **does not get calculated** for some reason, so sorting on it won't work. It gives the following result -

```
+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+------------+---------+
| index | point_x       | point_y        | point_z        | lat_lon_id | place_id   | sq_dist |
+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+------------+---------+
|     0 | 1636407.74908 | -2220902.79092 | -5744766.34094 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     1 | 1674317.79921 | -2157598.66673 | -5757951.69661 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     2 | 1652089.75753 | -2193845.00579 | -5750671.55762 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     3 | 1621803.74283 | -2184916.54092 | -5762679.25265 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     4 | 1615277.72619 | -2200110.86847 | -5758729.88373 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     5 | 1652642.77785 | -2208303.65375 | -5744975.77555 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     6 | 1618985.40684 | -2190362.00049 | -5761404.37734 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     7 | 1621151.08717 | -2208242.04656 | -5753965.24636 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     8 | 1663760.68219 | -2166853.74959 | -5757536.37073 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
|     9 | 1639392.08560 | -2136418.33191 | -5775871.37502 |     433534 |    8529197 |    NULL |
+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

I have been banging my head against this all night, I tried using `GROUP BY` but I have always had a hard time understanding it's mysterious ways. There *should* be a way of getting only the minimum distance one for each point using `GROUP BY`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone else think of a way of making this work?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out myself using `GROUP BY`. Here's the modified query that works -

```
SELECT t.latlon_id, t.place_id, t.latitude, t.longitude, t.indx, (@dist:=(pow(t.sq_dist, 0.5)/1000)) as dist from (
    SELECT place.latlon_id, place.place_id, place.latitude, place.longitude, place.x, place.y, place.z, point.indx, point.xx, point.yy, point.zz,
        (@sq_dist:=(pow(point.xx-place.x, 2) + pow(point.yy-place.y, 2) + pow(point.zz-place.z, 2))) AS sq_dist
    FROM (
            SELECT 0 AS indx, 1636407.74908 AS xx, -2220902.79092 AS yy, -5744766.34094 AS zz
      UNION SELECT 1,          1674317.79921,      -2157598.66673,      -5757951.69661
      UNION SELECT 2,          1652089.75753,      -2193845.00579,      -5750671.55762
      UNION SELECT 3,          1621803.74283,      -2184916.54092,      -5762679.25265
      UNION SELECT 4,          1615277.72619,      -2200110.86847,      -5758729.88373
      UNION SELECT 5,          1652642.77785,      -2208303.65375,      -5744975.77555
      UNION SELECT 6,          1618985.40684,      -2190362.00049,      -5761404.37734
      UNION SELECT 7,          1621151.08717,      -2208242.04656,      -5753965.24636
      UNION SELECT 8,          1663760.68219,      -2166853.74959,      -5757536.37073
      UNION SELECT 9,          1639392.0856,       -2136418.33191,      -5775871.37502
    ) as point
    JOIN geonames_geonamelookup place
    WHERE place.geoname_id IN (
        4030764,4030734,4030752,3948666,4030743,4030751,4030742,4030740,4030757,4030733,4030763,4030748,4030741,
        4030735,4030744,4030753,4030737,4030736,4030731,8030076,4030739,6930873,4030727,4030758,4030726,8261466,
        4030801,4030756,4030730,4030759,7840188,7911304,4030762,4030728,4030729,6531602,4030755,4030754,4030760,
        4030749,4030750,4030761,8224616,4030738,4030732,4030746,4030747,4030745,4030871,4030872,4030790,4030787,
        3948662,4030797,4030791,4030775,4030794,4030772,4030796,4030798,3948648,4030792,4030789,4030773,4030799,
        3948661,3948651,4030788,4030778,3948657,4030800,4030795,4030793,4020117,4020363,3948663,4030777,3948658,
        3948650,4030776,4020292,4020210,3948649,4030717,3969465,3969459,4030779,4030704,4030694,4030713,8529197,
        4030873,3733656,3948664,4030786,4030781,4030783
    ) ORDER BY sq_dist
) as t GROUP BY t.indx;
```

MySQL `GROUP BY` is not intuitive at all...

**EDIT:** **Note that the above query is very slow and not scalable at all**, currently, what I am doing from python code that seems to be running nice and fast is,

```
count = len(xyz_s)
dist_phrase = ', (pow(x-%s, 2) + pow(y-%s, 2) + pow(z-%s, 2))' * count
query = """
        select place_id, latlon_id, latitude, longitude {dist_phrase} from place_table where place_id in ({nbrs})
""".format(dist_phrase=dist_phrase, nbrs=nbrs)  % tuple(a for xyz in xyz_s for a in xyz)
cursor.execute(query)
```

This now gives me number of rows equal to the number of places to lookup from, and  additional columns containing square distance of each of the points provided, I further determine the closest place to each point within python itself.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think you're using an undocumented feature of GROUP BY (i.e. a 'hack'). But hey, if it works, then that's cool, right?

Comment: Yay it works, but for small inputs, with ~50,000 rows to filter from the table containing 10 million rows and ~1000 x,y,z values the `UNION SELECT`, 3 derived tables and a cross join... I think, it just becomes too much for the database, query takes forever...(I killed it after half an hour) on the other hand, the method I mentioned in the edit works wonders! just 2 secs for the same input I mentioned above...